# Strange failure to make a HIT for Amazon Mechanical Turk with some URLs?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I was trying to include a link in a HIT request in Amazon Mechanical Turk, using boto, and kept getting an error that my XML was invalid.  I gradually pared my html down to the bare minimum, and isolated that it seems to be that some valid links fail for seemingly no reason.  Can anyone with expertise in boto or aws help me parse why?

I followed these two guides:

- http://www.toforge.com/2011/04/boto-mturk-tutorial-create-hits/
- https://gist.github.com/j2labs/740267

Here is my example:

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
from boto.mturk.question import QuestionContent,Question,QuestionForm,Overview,AnswerSpecification,SelectionAnswer,FormattedContent,FreeTextAnswer
from config import *

HOST = 'mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com'

mtc = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                      host=HOST)

title = 'HIT title'
description = ("HIT description.")
keywords = 'keywords'

s1 = """<![CDATA[<p>Here comes a link <a href='%s'>LINK</a></p>]]>""" % "http://www.example.com"
s2 = """<![CDATA[<p>Here comes a link <a href='%s'>LINK</a></p>]]>""" % "https://www.google.com/search?q=example&site=imghp&tbm=isch"

def makeahit(s):
    overview = Overview()
    overview.append_field('Title', 'HIT title itself')
    overview.append_field('FormattedContent',s)

    qc = QuestionContent()
    qc.append_field('Title','The title')

    fta = FreeTextAnswer()

    q = Question(identifier="URL",
                 content=qc,
                 answer_spec=AnswerSpecification(fta))

    question_form = QuestionForm()
    question_form.append(overview)
    question_form.append(q)

    mtc.create_hit(questions=question_form,
                   max_assignments=1,
                   title=title,
                   description=description,
                   keywords=keywords,
                   duration = 30,
                   reward=0.05)

makeahit(s1) # SUCCESS!
makeahit(s2) # FAIL?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in makeahit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/mturk/connection.py", line 263, in create_hit
    return self._process_request('CreateHIT', params, [('HIT', HIT)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/mturk/connection.py", line 821, in _process_request
    return self._process_response(response, marker_elems)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/mturk/connection.py", line 836, in _process_response
    raise MTurkRequestError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.mturk.connection.MTurkRequestError: MTurkRequestError: 200 OK
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CreateHITResponse><OperationRequest><RequestId>19548ab5-034b-49ec-86b2-9e499a3c9a79</RequestId></OperationRequest><HIT><Request><IsValid>False</IsValid><Errors><Error><Code>AWS.MechanicalTurk.XHTMLParseError</Code><Message>There was an error parsing the XHTML data in your request.  Please make sure the data is well-formed and validates against the appropriate schema. Details: The reference to entity "site" must end with the ';' delimiter. Invalid content: &lt;FormattedContent&gt;&lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;Here comes a link &lt;a href='https://www.google.com/search?q=example&amp;site=imghp&amp;tbm=isch'&gt;LINK&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;&lt;/FormattedContent&gt; (1369323038698 s)</Message></Error></Errors></Request></HIT></CreateHITResponse>
```

Any idea why s2 fails, but s1 succeeds when both are valid links?  Both link contents work:

- http://www.example.com
- https://www.google.com/search?q=example&site=imghp&tbm=isch

Things with query strings?  Https?

**UPDATE**

I'm going to do some tests, but right now my candidate hypotheses are:

1. HTTPS doesn't work (so, I'll see if I can get another https link to work)
2. URLs with params don't work (so, I'll see if I can get another url with params to work)
3. Google doesn't allow its searches to get posted this way? (if 1 and 2 fail!)

Comment: Do you need to xml escape the urls?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought that's what CDATA did.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: That should be true, but thought it would be worth a try.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No, but I didn't pursue my update ideas yet.

Comment: I'm almost certain the API endpoint is broken and you have to escape your URL's even though it's in `CDATA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape ampersands in urls, i.e. `&` => `&amp;`.

At the end of s2, use

```
q=example&amp;site=imghp&amp;tbm=isch
```

instead of

```
q=example&site=imghp&tbm=isch
```

Comment: Amp is normally "%26", right?  But isn't & allowed in URLS?  That URL when entered into my url bar actually works, with the &.  That's how google queries natively, look.  Are you saying this is a restriction via amazon, or something else I should be aware of?

Comment: It's XML escaping, which is different than the escaping you need in a URL. & is allowed in URLs, but the file that Amazon is reading from is XML, so when it sees '&' it thinks that it is the start of a special character.

Comment: Here's a helpful discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters